# I get Build failed error when adding migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webapi

when i use `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` i got build failed error.

[image]

[image]

When i run dotnet build i got yellow errors.

I'm available to run dotnet run but i need to create migrations file for my project.

And i need to use sdk 2.2 for my project so i can't use new versions of sdk's. Beacause they don't have startup.cs file.

And i also tryed dotnet ef database update.

Anyone can help me for this error?

Startup.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using rentapi.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace rentapi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddDbContextPool<DataContext>(options=> options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBCS")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

DataContext.cs file

```
using rentapi.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace rentapi.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options):base(options){}


        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

appsetting.json file

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBCS":"Server=.; Database=rent; Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: "And i need to use sdk 2.2 for my project so i can't use new versions of sdk's. Beacause they don't have startup.cs file." - You can have startup file in any version

Add `--verbose` to your query so you can see the output.
If you think everything is fine, you can add `--no-build` option.

Comment: I'm making a project by watching a video, so it has to be startup.cs. Because I'm new to c#.

Comment: can you open your project with visual studio and run command add-migration(other command depand)

Comment: I removed the visual studio because of sdk problem. Is there a way for vscode?

Comment: First make sure that your program has no error by run the following command `dotnet build` ... if it gives you errors solve it first because Migration will not add in your project if you have compiled time errors

Comment: 1.First go to this path (TaskMangage>Resource Monitor>cpu>Associated Handles) and search path and Close all of apps displayed  2.run your command (if you get error please run command build)

Comment: when i search C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rent\rentapi path on Associated Handles I came across dotnet.exe and explorer.exe applications, should I close them?

Comment: I think you have forgotten to add some package you can check the below package    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools  or     eMicrosoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design or if you have NLayer Project you need to add the below package in your endpoint layer Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design